# What is the difference between the Ureter and Urethra? also between the Renal papilla and Renal pelvis?

Tags: homework, kidney

Differentiate between the following:

1. Ureter and Urethra
2. Renal papilla and Renal pelvis

It is not given in my book.
Please help.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework question...

Comment: Yup, it is. But it is not given in my book. So I needed help.

Comment: @siddhu99 See our [homework policy](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq) for reasons your question may have been downvoted.

Comment: overall though, homework is okay though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ureters run from the kidneys to the bladder whilst the urethra runs from the bladder to exit the body:

[image: Schematic of urethra and ureters]

The renal papillae are the site where urine drains into one of the minor calyxes of the kidney.   Multiple minor calyxes join together into a major calyx, and multiple major calyxes join together to form the renal pelvis which then drains into the ureter.

[image: Kidney]